# Is it possible to take one portion of a multi-index from the rows of a dataframe and apply it as columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with multi-indexed rows and a single index columns. "foo" is just the first EntityType, I will have others which will make this dataframe longer and harder to view.

[image]

I'd like to take the aggregation method index column and move it to the columns so I have a table like this

| Entity Type | Quantile Range | bar |  |  |  | baz |  |  |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  | max | avg | std | total | max | avg | std | total |
| foo | q99-q100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| foo | q90-q99 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| foo | q70-q90 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| foo | q0-q70 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| quix | q99-q100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| quix | q90-q99 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| quix | q70-q90 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| quix | q0-q70 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| maz | q99-q100 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| maz | q90-q99 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| maz | q70-q90 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| maz | q0-q70 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

Is there an easy command to do this? Something like Melt or reset index? I'm just not even sure where to being googling to get the answer.

Comment: You can use [`.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for this: `df.unstack()`.  This unstacks the last level, but you can specify this if you want to.

Comment: You can try pivot with index as foo and quantile, columns as AggregationMethod and values as bar and baz

Comment: @Rawson Unstack was exactly what I needed -- if you want to post it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting my comment as an answer:

You can use [.unstack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) for this, which does as the name suggests, removing the level of the MultiIndex to create a multi column index:

```
df.unstack()
```

This unstacks the last level by default, but you can specify this if you want to either with `level="AggregationMethod"`, `level=-1` (the default) or `level=2`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example of how to do it with Pandas [pivot](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), as suggested in the comments, and [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```py
import random

import pandas as pd

# Toy dataframe (same as yours after reseting the index)
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "Entity Type": ["foo" for _ in range(20)],
        "Quantile Range": ["q99_q100", "q90_q99", "q70_q90", "q00_q70"] * 5,
        "AggregationMethod": ["max", "avg", "std", "total", "count"] * 4,
        "bar": [random.uniform(1, 999) for _ in range(20)],
        "baz": [random.uniform(1, 999) for _ in range(20)],
    }
)
```

```py
df = df.pivot(
    index=["Entity Type", "Quantile Range"],
    columns="AggregationMethod",
    values=["bar", "baz"],
).reindex(["max", "avg", "std", "total"], level=1, axis=1)
```

```py
print(df)
# Output

                                   bar
AggregationMethod                  max         avg         std       total   
Entity Type Quantile Range
foo         q00_q70         141.752307  822.270987  199.740853  595.444166  \
            q70_q90         383.574450  410.730888  838.562828  545.299705   
            q90_q99         339.588340  606.983173  935.142608  407.674059   
            q99_q100        161.833517  932.267262  157.149458  618.105967   

                                   baz
AggregationMethod                  max         avg         std       total  
Entity Type Quantile Range
foo         q00_q70          17.986766  298.760555  389.559554   49.925246  
            q70_q90         888.435092  695.713473  502.429534  209.356226  
            q90_q99         715.425998  209.749918  136.480141  525.729657  
            q99_q100        705.721265  956.273655  684.883477   39.114393
```